# How to center an element in wpf canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, wpf-positioning

How can I center an element in wpf canvas using attached properties?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Something like this.

```
double left = (Canvas.ActualWidth - element.ActualWidth) / 2;
Canvas.SetLeft(element, left);

double top  = (Canvas.ActualHeight - element.ActualHeight) / 2;
Canvas.SetTop(element, top);
```

Comment: can this be written inside a class which inherits a canvas class as an attached property.

Answer (score 48):

I came across this post, because I was searching for a way to center an element within a Canvas in XAML only, instead of using Attached Properties.

Just in case, you came for the same reason:

```
<Canvas x:Name="myCanvas">
    <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=myCanvas}" 
          Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=myCanvas}">
        <Label Content="Hello World!"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        />
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

#### One more thing, though

Beware that every solution here is a trap, depending on what you try to achieve. Just because your element is within the `Canvas` on a hierarchical order, it will not be part of the `Canvas` itself. A `Canvas` is something to draw on and not to place controls in. So you cannot use the `Canvas` API for those controls, because the `Grid` is like an isolated overlay, obviously.

If you want a separated overlay, whilst the `Canvas` is your background, you are good to go with this solution.

Comment: Awesome! This works "as is", with no code behind. I used it to center a UserControl, in the place of the Label.

Comment: Now there is a slow Grid inside. A solution without a Grid would be nice.

Comment: @MathiasMüller There's nothing to stop you using any other control in place of the Grid.

Comment: Save my day. I did not though to add a grid to handle the layout. Thank you @MartinBraun

Answer (score 10):

The only way I know to do this is to figure out the size of the canvas, and then set the properties based off that. This can be done using an event handler for `SizeChanged` on the canvas:

```
parentCanvas.SizeChanged += new SizeChangedEventHandler(parentCanvas_SizeChanged);

void parentCanvas_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    parentCanvas.SetLeft(uiElement, (parentCanvas.ActualWidth - uiElement.ActualWidth) / 2);
    parentCanvas.SetTop(uiElement, (parentCanvas.ActualHeight - uiElement.ActualHeight) / 2);
}
```

Comment: will this event fire on load of the window.

Comment: It should, yes. It will fire whenever the ActualWidth/ActualHeight properties of the canvas are changed. (i.e. during layout updating)

Comment: Great. But I believe it should be Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetTop; not the instance of the parent Canvas.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the Canvas and the element you want to be centered inside a Grid :

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Width="200" Height="200" Background="Black" />
    <Button Width="50" Height="20" > Hello
    </Button>
</Grid>
```