# Insert Image as Polygon Content

Tags: c#, wpf, image, polygon

I want to insert an `Image` inside my `Polygon`, possibly at the center of the `Polygon`. Is it possible? How can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ImageBrush` as the polygon's `Fill`. Like this:

```
<Polygon.Fill>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="sampleImages\berries.jpg"
                AlignmentX="..." AlignmentY="..." />
</Polygon.Fill>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change the Polygon Fill.

Comment: Then you can clip the image with a `PolygonGeometry`. See [Cropping or Clipping in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/cropping-or-clipping-in-wpf/). For help with centering, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208992/how-to-center-an-element-in-wpf-canvas

Comment: [Here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=A61D8C70C8903DDC!4937)'s an example.

Answer (score 0):

May be "Points" attribute help you :

```
<Polygon Points="40,0 150,100 10,100" >
   <Polygon.Fill>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Left" />
   </Polygon.Fill>
</Polygon>
```